# Where does the lib come from in typecsript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a typescript@2 project. I wanted to use some ecma2017 features. I found out that one can apply a `lib` in the `compilerOptions` in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
"target": "es6",
"lib": [
    "es2017",
    "dom"
],
```

Yet why is this working? Where do these lib come from, what libs can one include?

The closest to a documentation I could find was this [this what's new entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#downlevel-async-functions):

> ## Downlevel Async Functions
>
> This feature was supported before TypeScript 2.1, but only when targeting ES6/ES2015. TypeScript 2.1 brings the capability to ES3 and
>   ES5 run-times, meaning you'll be free to take advantage of it no
>   matter what environment you're using.
>
> Note: first, we need to make sure our run-time has an ECMAScript-compliant Promise available globally. That might involve
>   grabbing a polyfill for Promise, or relying on one that you might have
>   in the run-time that you're targeting. We also need to make sure that
>   TypeScript knows Promise exists by setting your lib flag to something
>   like "dom", "es2015" or "dom", "es2015.promise", "es5"

yet I didn't find it particular helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All values of the compiler options `lib` is referenced in the [Lib documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#high-level-libraries):

```
List of library files to be included in the 

Possible values are: 
► ES5 
► ES6 
► ES2015 
► ES7 
► ES2016 
► ES2017 
► ESNext 
► DOM 
► DOM.Iterable 
► WebWorker 
► ScriptHost 
► ES2015.Core 
► ES2015.Collection 
► ES2015.Generator 
► ES2015.Iterable 
► ES2015.Promise 
► ES2015.Proxy 
► ES2015.Reflect 
► ES2015.Symbol 
► ES2015.Symbol.WellKnown 
► ES2016.Array.Include 
► ES2017.object 
► ES2017.SharedMemory 
► esnext.asynciterable 

Note: If --lib is not specified a default library is injected. The default library injected is: 
► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost
```